# File assciation screen is not updated when components are re-selected

Tags: install4j, file-association

I have an install4j installer with multiple components. For each component, a file association is registered with the proper condition:

```
context.getInstallationComponentById("1").isSelected()
```

After the user selects the components, he gets to the file associations screen, where - correctly - only those file associations are offered that fit the selected components.

When the user goes back some screens and changes the selected components, however, the file associations screen is not updated and still shows the previous list of associations.

Can I force an update on this screen somehow?

I am using install4j Windows Edition 6.1.1 (build 6254).

Comment: How do you change the selection state of the file association actions? Their condition expression does not have any influence on the file associations screen.

Comment: Well, it does for me. See the sample that I uploaded to https://spaces.hightail.com/space/M5S7nQG5tT

Comment: OK, now I get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not possible and will be fixed in 7.0.10. Please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get a pre-release build.